# How to compare only key names in a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, compare, response

I'm working on a Python script that compares two JSON responses (`example_response.json` and `actual_response.json`) and identifies differing keys. The script uses a recursive function, `compare_json_keys`, to traverse through the nested structures of the JSON objects.

The goal is to highlight any extra keys in either response and indicate the specific paths where the differences occur. The script seems to be functioning as expected, but I received a comment suggesting that my post lacks sufficient details.

Could someone please review the code and provide feedback on whether there are potential improvements or if I can clarify any aspects? Additionally, if there are alternative approaches to achieve the same goal, I would appreciate suggestions.

Thank you!

```
import json
import os

def compare_json_keys(actual_dict, example_dict, current_path=''):
    differing_keys = set(actual_dict.keys()) ^ set(example_dict.keys())
    extra_keys_actual = set(actual_dict.keys()) - set(example_dict.keys())
    extra_keys_example = set(example_dict.keys()) - set(actual_dict.keys())

    # Check for missing keys in one of the dictionaries
    if not differing_keys:
        if extra_keys_actual:
            for key in extra_keys_actual:
                print(f"Actual response has extra key in {current_path}.{key}")
        if extra_keys_example:
            for key in extra_keys_example:
                print(f"Example response has extra key in {current_path}.{key}")

    # Recursive comparison of keys
    for key in set(actual_dict.keys()) & set(example_dict.keys()):
        path = f"{current_path}.{key}" if current_path else key

        if isinstance(actual_dict[key], dict) and isinstance(example_dict[key], dict):
            # Recursive call to compare nested objects
            differing_keys |= compare_json_keys(actual_dict[key], example_dict[key], current_path=path)
        elif isinstance(actual_dict[key], list) and isinstance(example_dict[key], list):
            # Recursive call to compare nested lists
            for i, (item_actual, item_example) in enumerate(zip(actual_dict[key], example_dict[key])):
                differing_keys |= compare_json_keys(item_actual, item_example, current_path=f"{path}[{i}]")
        elif key in extra_keys_actual or key in extra_keys_example:
            differing_keys.add(path)

    return differing_keys


# Get the path to the folder containing the script and JSON files
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Form full paths to the JSON files
example_response_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'example_response.json')
actual_response_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'actual_response.json')

# Read JSON files and convert them to dictionaries
with open(example_response_path, 'r') as file1, open(actual_response_path, 'r') as file2:
    example_response = json.load(file1)
    actual_response = json.load(file2)

# Compare field names in the responses
differing_keys = compare_json_keys(actual_response, example_response)
if not differing_keys:
    print("Both responses have the same set of fields.")
else:
    print("Differing keys:")
    for key in differing_keys:
        file_origin = 'example' if key in example_response else 'actual'
        print(f"{key} in {file_origin} response")
```